# Paper size for books & custom class

Tags: document-classes, paper-size

I noticed that some books written in TeX have a smaller page size than the usual articles. Specifically, I'm looking at the [Language Science Press](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/language-science-press-template-2016-slash-05-edited-volumes/dxfqwympmgxk#.W1xfwy1aZQY) template, which seems to use a smaller page size. My question is, how can I obtain the same results? I'm pretty new to TeX so I'm not sure how to proceed. I'm using TexMaker, if that can help.

Also, since I'm in the process of writing a linguistics book, I was wondering what the best class for it would be, or how I can write my own custom class for tables and titles. Finally, will I be allowed to sell this book if I use a pre-existing class file once I'm done with it? Thank you.

Comment: The page size is independent of the document class.  One can specify certain page sizes using the document class optons.  One can specify a completely arbitrary page size using the geometry package.  Book class is the standard for books, but others prefer things like KOMA and memoir.

Answer (score 2):

The `memoir` class provides many options for the stock (what you feed into the printer) and page (the printed area) sizes. There are also facilities for specifying what you want if the options aren't sufficient. See chapters One and Two in the manual (`> texdoc memoir`). You may also find *A Few Notes on Book Design* (`> texdoc memdesign`) useful.

I'm not a lawyer but I don't think that there are any restrictions on selling your printed work, however you produced it. It may be different if you wanted to sell the source but most LaTeX classes and packages are released under the LPPL which essentially has few restrictions (somebody correct me if I'm wrong) but I assume that you wouldn't be trying to sell the class/package code itself, just your use of them.